# How to handle errors from Fileutils cd

Tags: ruby, methods, fileutils

I'm having troubles when using Fileutils method in ruby

When using:

```
FileUtils.cd("A/non/existing/directory")
```

I get an error output as expected but my ruby script violently ends.

Question is how can I prevent my ruby script from stopping when I try to access to a
non existing directory?

I found this:

```
FileUtils.cd('/', :verbose => true)   # chdir and report it
```

but it doesn't work, or at least I don't know how the syntax works!

Comment: why you want to catch the exception,on rescue what else you would like to perform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script "violently ends" because `FileUtils.cd` throws an exception when the directory does not exist. Because your script does not handle the exception, it exits.

Wrap your code in a `begin`-`rescue`-block like this to handle the exception:

```
require 'fileutils'

begin
  FileUtils.cd "A/non/existing/directory"
rescue Errno::ENOENT => e
  # do things for appropriate error handling
  puts e.message
end
```

The `Errno::ENOENT` exception is thrown when the directory change fails. In the `rescue` block you may handle the exception (here I just output the error message).